# Jest Testing - Typescript error with random number generation

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

This is the error. Unsure how I can predict a decimal value and what changed that the tests have been failing with the error, the only chnages I made were to the versions in package.json

- Added "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.2.6",
- Change "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3" and "@emotion/styled-base": "^10.0.27",

```
clients › instrumentPromise › should log on promise rejecting

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "groupNamespace": "global",
    -   "milliseconds": 0,
    +   "milliseconds": 0.05922000000009575,
        "operationName": "name",
        "success": false,
      },

    Number of calls: 1

      64 |                 void instrumentPromise(promise, "name").catch(() => {
      65 |                     // eslint-disable-next-line jest/no-conditional-expect
    > 66 |                     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
         |                                 ^
      67 |                         groupNamespace: "global",
      68 |                         milliseconds: 0,
      69 |                         operationName: "name",

      at src/utils/clients/clients.test.ts:66:33
```

My versions - package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
        "@amzn/brazil": "*",
        "@amzn/meridian": "*",
        "@amzn/meridian-tokens": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-bluering-clickstream-client": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-bluering-webapp-context": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-clara-ruby-utils": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-meridian-tokens": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-profile-service": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-team-management-type-script-client": "*",
        "@emotion/core": "^10.3.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^10.3.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
        "aws-amplify": "4.3.17",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1096.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.2.3",
        "cognito-jwt-token-validator": "1.0.0",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "emotion": "^10.0.27",
        "i18next": "^21.6.14",
        "qrcode.react": "^1.0.0",
        "query-string": "^7.1.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-i18next": "^11.16.1",
        "react-query": "^3.39.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "use-copy": "^0.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@amzn/brazil": "*",
        "@amzn/browserslist-config-santos-bluering": "*",
        "@amzn/eslint-plugin-santos-bluering": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-bluering-common-config": "*",
        "@amzn/santos-ui-components": "^1.0.0",
        "@amzn/string-localization-validator": "*",
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
        "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.10.5",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
        "@emotion/styled-base": "^10.0.27",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.4",
        "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.8",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.8",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.2.8",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
        "@types/qrcode.react": "^1.0.2",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
        "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.15.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.2.2",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "core-js": "^3.21.1",
        "cspell": "^5.19.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.1",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^7.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.2.6",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.4",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.5.1",
        "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
        "mini-svg-data-uri": "^1.4.4",
        "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
        "npm-check-updates": "^12.5.4",
        "postcss": "^8.4.12",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.2",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "react-hooks-testing-library": "^0.6.0",
        "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.6.2",
        "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^3.4.0",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.70.0",
        "webpack-assets-manifest": "^5.1.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.x",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the issue is that you are getting a value in milliseconds that you cannot predict and was previously 0? (Not sure why you think this is a TS issue).

Easiest way to solve it is to expect anything for a value of milliseconds:

```
      64 |                 void instrumentPromise(promise, "name").catch(() => {
      65 |                     // eslint-disable-next-line jest/no-conditional-expect
      66 |                     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
         |                                 
      67 |                         groupNamespace: "global",
      68 |                         milliseconds: expect.any(Number), // Just expect any number, you cannot predict random decimals. Or round down, and expect 0, if the result matters for what you are trying to test. but I assume it is something like elapsed time?
      69 |                         operationName: "name",
```

Of course it might be better to figure out why milliseconds was 0 and is now a number. But without context it is hard to help with that. You could look into what changed in the libraries you updated. Update them one by one to see which caused the change in behaviour and go through the changes in their git to find what causes the issue.